# Every keypress insert a character into a hidden text input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a specific character say the letter "H" every time a key is pressed in another text box.

Eg.

Text box 1: Type your name

Text box 2: HHHHHHHHHHHHHH

I have tried

```
$('#cartText16132').keyup( function() {
    $('input#test').val('1');
});
```

But that only inserts one "1"

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do what you want:

```
$("#cartText16132").keyup(function() {
    $("#test").val(this.value.replace(/./g, "H"));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JhpHL/

---

Another solution without regular expressions:

```
$("#cartText16132").keyup(function() {
    $("#test").val(Array(this.value.length + 1).join("H"));
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JhpHL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cartText16132').keyup( function(e) {
    $('input#test').val('H');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
$('#cartText16132').keyup( function() {
  var input = $('input#test');
  input.val( input.val() + "H" );
});
```

The problem is that you replace the value each time, you don't append it. So you replace your '1' with a '1' resulting in '1' not '11'.

Comment: Try to use `backspace`, or `alt`, or `ctrl`, any non symbolic key.

Comment: Thats what he asked for right? Not to have the same length as the text in the other text box, but add a H every time a key is pressed inside the other text box.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting the value with each keyup. You need to append:

$('input#test').val($('input#test').val()+'1');